# Trash value randomly added to array

Tags: arrays, c

I'm initialising a 3d array of `struct node` pointers and for some reason, sometimes a garbage value will randomly get added to my array. Here is the relevant code:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    new->dp[i] = malloc(3*sizeof(int*));
    for (int j=0; j<3; ++j) {
        new->dp[i][j] = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
        for (int k=0; k<=n; ++k) {
            new->dp[i][j][k] = new_node(0, null);  /* every entry starts at 0 */
            printf("i: %d, j: %d, k: %d, dp[i][j][k]->data: %d.\n", i, j, k, (new->dp[i][j][k])->data);
            if (j>0&&k>0) printf("seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: %d.\n", (new->dp[0][1][1])->data);
        }
    }
}
```

About half the time with `n=10`, it seems to work fine. The other half, I get this peculiar output:

```
i: 0, j: 1, k: 1, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 0.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 2, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 0.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 3, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 0.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 4, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 0.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 5, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 0.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 6, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 0.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 7, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 0.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 8, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 1884296384.
i: 0, j: 1, k: 9, dp[i][j][k]->data: 0.
seq->dp[0][1][1]->data: 1884296384.
```

When `k=8`, the data in the `dp[0][1][1]` node has all of a sudden turned into some trash value! It's always when `k=8`, but the value changes between runs of the program. It also doesn't change again for the whole rest of the program. For reference, here is my node struct:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* new_node(int i, struct node *after) {
    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = i;
    new->next = after;
}
```

Would anyone be able to tell me why this is happening sometimes? It doesn't seem to happen when `n<10`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you allocate memory for `new->dp`? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of your array are pointers to nodes. But you're allocating space for integers, not pointers. Unless integers and pointers are the same size (not likely these days), you're not allocating enough space. It should be:

```
new->dp[i][j] = malloc((n+1)*sizeof(struct node*));
```

Comment: Oops! What a dumb mistake! I had integers there previously, and forgot to update the malloc when i changed it to nodes. Thanks!